# What are the differences between The Sims 3: Pets on Windows and Xbox 360?

Tags: the-sims-3, version-differences

I am trying to determine the difference between *The Sims 3: Pets* on Windows and Xbox 360.

So far I've looked at the [Origins store page](http://store.origin.com/store/ea/en_US/custom/pbPage.FP_Sims3_en_NA#234872200), [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Sims_3:_Pets) (focused on the PC version), and IGN pages for the [PC](http://www.ign.com/games/the-sims-3-plus-pets/pc-110375) and [Xbox 360](http://www.ign.com/games/the-sims-3-plus-pets/xbox-360-110376) versions.

What content is the same, what is different, and how does *Pets* interact with the base game?

Answer (score 2):

**Base game**

- **Windows:** Requires base game. Adds new town, Appaloosa Plains. *?Otherwise does not interact with base game.*  *?New features are only available in new town.*
- **Xbox 360:** Does not require base game. Does not interact with base game even if you have it.

**Regular features**

- **Windows:** Regular features (Sims, houses, etc) in base game and new town.
- **Xbox 360:** Regular features as in base game, even without the base game, but limited only to the new town.*

**Pet feature**

- **Windows:**  Be the pet, pet adventures, pet traits, pet abilities (e.g. hunt).
- **Xbox 360:** Pet features as above.

**Voice commands**

- **Windows:** No voice commands.
- **Xbox 360:** Voice commands (requires Kinect).

**Limited edition (of Pets)**

- **Windows:** Adds pet store, additional fur patterns, animals (e.g. unicorn)
- **Xbox 360:** *? NO HORSES.  Adoption agency, but no official pet "store"; can purchase pet items via the build & buy mode.